# NoClassDefFoundError for custom annotation processor in Android Studio 3.0

Tags: java, android, annotations, android-studio-3.0

I have a custom annotation processor which parses XML files. It was working fine with `Android Studio 2.3.3`, now I have updated `Android Studio to version 3.0`(Stable), it suddenly started throwing `NoClassDefFound` error for the annotation of my annotation processor.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'.
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: io/github/***/annotations/****
```

In Gradle

```
   compile  'io.github.allaudin:****:1.0.0'
   annotationProcessor  'io.github.allaudin:****-processor:1.0.0'
```

Comment: I have found that `compile` is deprecated and `implementation` is new version of `compile`. I have made this update but still annotation can not be found at compile time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK. Got it worked by stetting `includeCompileClasspath` to `true` in `build.gradle`.

```
android {
    ...
    defaultConfig {
       ...
        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                includeCompileClasspath true
            }
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: just keep in mind, that his is just a workaround (now you have the whole compile-classpath on your processor-path) and also that this feature will be removed in the future see the [android docs](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#disable_the_annotation_processor_error_check)

Comment: Thanks for informing. What's the proper way? Should I package annotations with processor too?

Comment: No. The annotations should be in the main library-jar (which you add to the compile-classpath) and the processor project should just declare a dependency on the library jar (because it also needs the annotations): as mentioned in another comment, this is what other projects do: e.g. [immutables value-processor pom.xml](https://github.com/immutables/immutables/blob/master/value-processor/pom.xml)

Comment: That's what I am doing but still I need to add processor in class path. I don't know what's wrong with Android Studio 3.0.

Comment: I am quite sure, that nothing is wrong with AS3.0. I use many libs with annotation processors. It is very likely that the problem is with your annotation processor. Since you cannot post the source-code, I can just point you to examples: e.g. you can try to make the `immutables-value` work in a sample project and then compare it to your own annotation processor project.

Answer (score 0):

You must migrate to the new android gradle plugin: follow [these steps](https://developer.android.com/studio/build/gradle-plugin-3-0-0-migration.html#annotationProcessor_config)

> In previous versions of the plugin, dependencies on the compile classpath were automatically added to the processor classpath. That is, you could add an annotation processor to the compile classpath and it would work as expected. However, this causes a significant impact to performance by adding a large number of unnecessary dependencies to the processor.
>
> When using the Android plugin 3.0.0, you must add annotation processors to the processor classpath using the annotationProcessor dependency configuration, as shown below:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    annotationProcessor 'com.google.dagger:dagger-compiler:<version-number>'
}
```

Comment: Yes. I am doing this.

Comment: then we need more info: the annotation (that is not found) is in the compile jar, right? can you maybe post a link to the sources?

Comment: I can see source code in Android Studio. What can possibly be wrong with this?

Comment: The classpath and processorpath are different: so if you have e.g. the java files of your annotation only on the processorpath, and use the annotation in your java-source-files, the compilation will fail, because [javac](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/solaris/javac.html) will only search the classpath

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Annotations are separate and are included as compile time dependency.

Comment: That is okay, but you must make sure, that the annotations are also the annotation processor path: this is usually done via transitive dependencies: e.g. take a look at the build files of immutables projects: [value](https://github.com/immutables/immutables/tree/master/value) and [value-processor](https://github.com/immutables/immutables/tree/master/value-processor)

Comment: Yes. I got your point. I am doing similar thing here. Everything was working fine till Android Studio 2.3.3, I got this error after updating it to 3.0.